# use reflection get class name and method name

Tags: php, reflection

In my website there is folder named as plugins. I want to get all class used in that folder and method of each class.
But I don't know how can I use reflection to get method name and class name from that folder? Where should I write code for it?

Comment: What do you mean as used - already loaded in the application?

Comment: class defined in plugins floder

Comment: You should maintain a file or database table with your active plugins.

Comment: That is not possible...
I want to know methods of plugins and not plugins name.
I need to use reflection to get method names

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : you may use autoloader to load classes, you can collect all classes in an iteratable array if resource count indefinite.

Method 2 : you may use `get_declared_classes()` method to get all declared classes and match with regex which are point your plugin.

after all of it use reflection.

```
<?php
    foreach ($declaredClasses as $key => $classWithNamespace) {
        $class = new ReflectionClass($classWithNamespace);
        $methods = $class->getMethods();
        foreach ($methods as $method) {
           //analyze your methods
        }

}
```

But if you don't cache this things in your prod env. There would be many performance issues, reflection is not a cheap cost!